# Array as property in BreezeJS model

Tags: arrays, breeze, models

I'm creating a BreezeJS model and I would like to have an array as one of the property values, but I'm unsure how that would be set under the dataProperties section of the model.  Would anyone have a example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yo just define the property in your model as:

```
arrayOrObjectProperty:    { dataType: "Undefined" }
```

And it should be enough, also if you require some further processing, like expansion or formatting of the property (so in your controllers the data is ready) you could do it in the jsonResultsAdapter.